# Obtain RSSI with hcidump

Tags: linux, bluetooth, rssi, hci

In order to read the raw RSSI values, we use a utility called Hcidump, which monitors the Bluetooth HCI data. Using hcidump commands, we can read the raw RSSI values when an inquiry response message is received. To obtain RSSI values for every response packet we first set the inquiry mode to Inquiry With RSSI.In order to read raw RSSI values we run the hcidump tool and then use the appropriate
HCI functions to start periodic inquiry.

I don't know how to use hcidump to obatain only RSSI raw data or maybe how to  start a periodic inquiry. I see all the opcions but I am not able.

I make hcidump --raw  to obtain raw data, and try to parse this data to obtain the rssi, but I dont know wich hex is the rssi info.

This is what I obtain

```
  04 2F FF 01 AC A2 65 92 88 EC 01 00 0C 02 5A 2D 1F D2 08 09 
  4E 65 78 75 73 20 36 17 03 05 11 0A 11 0C 11 0E 11 12 11 15 
  11 16 11 1F 11 2F 11 00 12 32 11 01 05 01 07 00 00 00 00 00 
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Now I need to know which is the RSSI value.

Answer (score 2):

you can try using `sudo hcidump [-a]` this will get you the name and RSSI value of all the nearby bluetooth devices.you can check out what you can do with hcidump [here](http://maemo.org/development/documentation/man_pages/hcidump/).

Answer (score 0):

We can figure this out by inspecting the source code behind the `hcidump` tool. It is a part of [BlueZ](http://www.bluez.org/), the official Linux Bluetooth stack. You can download the BlueZ source code [here](http://www.bluez.org/download/), to follow along. If you open up the source code and step into `lib/` folder, you can find `hci.h`, which has the struct definitons for BlueZ's HCI functions. Otherwise, you can look in your Linux system's header files. The path should be something like: `/usr/include/bluetooth/hci.h`. In this header file, you will find all the struct definitions for BlueZ's HCI functionality. Specifically, you can find the struct defintion for `inquiry_info_with_rssi`. The header file is a few thousand lines long so you would be better served searching the header file instead of trying to look through it. From looking at this struct and the `#define` below, you can see the struct size is 14 bytes. The rssi value is the last member of the struct and only 1 byte, so it should be the 14th byte you count.

```
typedef struct {
bdaddr_t    bdaddr;
uint8_t     pscan_rep_mode;
uint8_t     pscan_period_mode;
uint8_t     dev_class[3];
uint16_t    clock_offset;
int8_t      rssi;
} __attribute__ ((packed)) inquiry_info_with_rssi;
#define INQUIRY_INFO_WITH_RSSI_SIZE 14
```

An interesting note is that `__attribute__ ((packed))` is a compiler preprocessor directing it not to pad the structure, so the size of 14 bytes is guranteed.