# How do we get RSSI values from Bluetooth beacons (estimote to be specific) in Linux?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, rssi

I need to get distances from multiple bluetooth beacons for triangulation so that I can do indoor positioning.
I have tried to give as many relevant details as possible. This project is for an RPi, but I am currently trying to test it through my laptop first. I have tried most of what I can find on the internet about this:

The best way I could find to get the rssi values was `hcitool rssi <address of beacon>`

From here [Bluetooth LE Signal Strength Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24417017/bluetooth-le-signal-strength-linux)

To test this, I tried to get it for my mobile first. It showed "`Not Connected`". I thought I need to connect first, so I tried many ways to connect my mobile:

a) `hcittol cc <address of mobile>`

b) `gatttool -b <address of mobile> -t random --interactive`

c) `rfcomm connect 0 <address of mobile> 10`

In each case, when I clicked pair in my mobile, connection terminated.

Then, I paired my mobile the usual way from bluetooth menu, and then tried `hcitool rssi <Address of mobile>` which then finally returned a value `-8`.

Now that I had it for my mobile, I now moved to beacons.

Then, I tried the same for my beacons. This time I had to 
first do `hcitool lescan` to get addresses of available beacons
then connect to one of the beacons using the command `hcitool lecc <address of beacon>` which returned the error `Could not create connection: Connection timed out`
So next, I again tried connecting with the other two ways:

`rfcomm connect 0 <address of beacon> 10` which returned the error `Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Host is down` when I can be sure hci0 was up.

Then I tried with `sudo gatttool -b F1:15:A7:E3:17:63 --interactive` after which interactive mode opened up and I gave the command `connect`. This gave different errors after `Attempting to connect to <address of beacon>`, 
mainly `connect error : Connection timed out` 
and `Error: connect error: Connection refused (111)`

Then I read I need to use `-t random` from [Bluetooth LE on Raspbian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213793/bluetooth-le-on-raspbian) , https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2204808 and one another source which I can't find right now.

So I entered `sudo gatttool -b F1:15:A7:E3:17:63 -t random --interactive` in which when I gave the `connect` command, I got error `Error: connect error: Device or resource busy (16)` and also sometimes `Error: connect error: Input/Output Error`

then I read that I perhaps need to restart my hci0 by `hciconfig hci0 down` and then `hciconfig hci0 up` which did the trick, the beacon now got connected.

But then, it quickly got disconnected after saying `GLib-WARNING **: Invalid file descriptor.

`
I read here https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/53982/how-to-fix-gatttools-glib-warning-invalid-file-descriptor that this is because of poor connections. I tried keeping the beacons closer, but it did the same.

So I tried to anyway at least get one rssi value during the short duration it is connected. But, even when it was thus connected, I did `hcitool rssi <address of beacon>` the error came like this:

```
hcitool rssi F1:15:A7:E3:17:63
Get connection info failed: No such file or directory
```

To which I haven't yet found a proper solution.

I tried another way of reading the rssi value, which gave the following :

```
hcidump -R
HCI sniffer - Bluetooth packet analyzer ver 5.37
device: hci0 snap_len: 1500 filter: 0xffffffffffffffff
> 04 0E 04 01 0B 20 00 
> 04 0E 04 01 0C 20 00 
> 04 0E 04 01 0C 20 00 
> 04 0F 04 00 01 0D 20 
> 04 0F 04 00 01 16 20 
> 04 0F 04 00 01 13 20
```

This was before it got disconnected.
I read here [Obtain RSSI with hcidump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37073114/obtain-rssi-with-hcidump) which said to read the 14th byte. since all these seemed to be hex numbers, this would mean that each number is 1 byte. But this way, I only have 7 numbers per line, how can I read the 14th byte?

Getting distance from beacons has been troubling me a lot, and has used up a a lot of my time. Please help me out on this issue. If you can help me find a resource to help me do so, I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to connect to a device to get the signal strength RSSI values, just use the following code and pipe that to a script that extracts values from the devices you are after:

```
btmon &
hcitool lescan --duplicates
```